# Allow the plus sign (+) in emails on the Stack Overflow Developer Survey

Tags: feature-request, survey-2017

A rarely known feature of emails is that `+` is [a valid character](http://www.jacobsen.no/anders/blog/archives/2002/08/24/email_addresses_with_a_are_valid.html). You can't register an email with it — instead it is [a special feature](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/plus-signs-in-email-addresses.html): if my email is `foo@example.com`, then I can provide `foo+tag@example.com` as my contact email. Those emails will arrive in `foo@example.com`'s inbox, but with `foo+tag@example.com` in the TO: field. (Since the `foo+tag@example.com` email address doesn't *really* exist and can't, it's not winding up in two separate destinations.) This is useful for tracking origins, email filtering, etc.

This feature's *so* rarely known however that most services don't even allow it; whoever wrote the email validation considered `+` to be an invalid character.

Stack Overflow's developer survey however did not allow me to provide an email of the format `foo+stackoverflowresearch@example.com`, which would have been very useful for highlighting the research email when I eventually received it.

I don't know if SO was really in control of that or if it was all up to Survey Monkey, but could they see what they could do, or give Survey Monkey a hard prod to update their email validation?

Comment: *"This feature's so rarely known however that most services don't even allow it"* I don't think that's true at all. I know a number of common services that support this, and certainly is a standard feature of all Unix-based mail systems.